# Accidentally merged in wrong branch to mine. Is there a way to remove these unwanted files?

Tags: git, merge

I accidentally merged a co-workers branch into the branch I was working on. I've made several commits since then so ideally I don't want to revert to the state the branch was before the merge. However, I haven't done anything that has altered his files.

Is there a way I can remove his branch's files from mine?

(Sorry, I am new to git - hope I've got the terminology down).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest and safest option here would be to revert the merge commit which you made a few commits ago.  To do this, find the merge commit in your history using `git log`, and record the SHA-1 hash of that commit.  Then, do the following:

```
git revert -m 1 <SHA-1>
```

Here `<SHA-1>` is the hash of the merge commit you want to undo.  The `-m 1` option tells Git to revert to the first parent, which is the branch on which the merge originated, which should be your branch.

Comment: As a new git user, thanks heaps for including the meaning of `<SHA-1>` and `-m 1`.

Comment: The drawback to this is that Git still believes the merge happened (because it did!), so this may give you heartburn later if you *want* to merge.

Answer (score 6):

If you have not pushed (published) your commits anywhere, the simplest fix is to rebase the merge away.  (You can do this even if you *have* published them, but see the caveat.)

The command `git rebase` *copies* commits, but by default, it *discards* merge commits.  The normal goal of `git rebase` is to copy commits so that they come at a different point.  For instance, you might have this:

```
...--o--*--o--o     <-- master
         \
          A--B--C   <-- yourbranch
```

in your repository after you pick up some new `master` commits from some "upstream" repository (`origin`), and now you'd like to make your `A-B-C` sequence come after the last commit on `master`, rather than coming after commit `*` (commit `*` is the first commit that is on *both* `master` *and* `yourbranch`).

You then `git checkout yourbranch && git rebase master` and Git copies the commits to new ones, `A'-B'-C'` (copies of the originals), and tosses your old ones:

```
                A'-B'-C'   <-- yourbranch
               /
...--o--*--o--o     <-- master
         \
          A--B--C   [abandoned]
```

But, since `git rebase` normally *discards* merges, you can rebase to where you are now, and in the process, toss out a merge:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o--...
         \     \
          A--B--X--C--D   <-- yourbranch
```

Here, your merge commit `X` is a mistake and you wish to get rid of it (I've drawn it as merging the mainline, but it could merge something else—it doesn't really matter *what* you merged, just that it *is* a merge commit, with two backwards-pointing arrows coming out of it, when Git looks at it).  So you find the hash ID of commit `*` and run:

```
git checkout yourbranch; git rebase <hash-id>
```

Git lists the commits to copy as "those after `*`, up to the tip of `yourbranch`, except for any merges".  That's `A-B-C-D`.  It then "copies" `A` (it doesn't have to so it actually re-uses the original `A` by default), "copies" `B` (again it doesn't have to), copies `C` (it has to this time—the original `C` connects to `X` and the new one must connect instead to `B`), and copies `D`, making `yourbranch` point to the last copied commit and abandoning the old chain:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o--...
         \     \
          A--B--X--C--D  [abandoned]
              \
               C'-D'  <-- yourbranch
```

With `D` abandoned, all three of `D`, `C` and `X` simply vanish off the map entirely:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o--...
         \
          A--B
              \
               C'-D'  <-- yourbranch
```

With `C` and `D` having vanished, we don't even need the `C'` and `D'` markings.  I will leave them in, though, and merely straighten out the kink we also no longer need:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o--...
         \
          A--B--C'-D'  <-- yourbranch
```

The commit message for `C'` looks like the one for `C`, and the one for `D'` looks like the one for `D`; and `C'` and `D'` are "just as good as" the originals—or, actually, even better: they're *new and improved!* :-) because they omit the merged stuff.

**Caveat:** Because these *are* "new and improved", they have new *hash IDs*.  This means that *if you have published them*, anyone who has the old ones will still have them, and will know them by their old hash IDs.  You must now convince these other Git users, with their other repositories, to *take* the new-and-improved copies and discard the old-and-lousy ones, just like you did.

If you *haven't* published these commits anywhere, no one else has the old ones, and there is nothing to worry about.

---

Note, by the way, that you can `git rebase` onto a new base, just as you would for updating to the latest `master`.  This just copies *all* the commits (to the new location), instead of re-using whichever commits it can (at the old location) and copying the rest.  (But you'll face any update-related issues when you do this, just as you would for any such rebase.  That is, if whoever updated `master`, or whatever it is you are updating to, touched the *same* code in the *same* files, you will have to resolve any merge conflicts that occur.  If you're only deleting a merge, and there were no merge conflicts in the merge, there won't be any in the rebase.)

Comment: Thanks for publishing this, very helpful. +1