# git: merge changes from a branch that reverted a previous merge

Tags: git, merge

Sorry for the confusing title, but I couldn't come up with a better one.

Here's my problem.  I have 2 branches, `develop` and `feature`.  I followed this process:

1. write code in `feature`
2. merge `feature` into `develop`
3. discover a bug, revert the merge
4. write some unrelated code and commit directly to `develop`.

Now I want to merge the changes I made directly to `develop` back into `feature`.  The problem is that when I do that, it blows away all the changes I had previously made in `feature`.  I assume this happens because the revert in step 3 is more recent than any code changes in `feature`, so it applies that revert over the changes.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?  The only thing I could think of is to revert the revert in `develop`, then merge, then revert the revert of the revert.  That seems kind of cumbersome.

Comment: See https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can rectify the situation in two steps:

1) Do an interactive rebase of `develop` and remove the revert commit, i.e.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~6    # or however far back is the merge commit
```

Delete the line containing the revert commit and complete the rebase.  At this point, `develop` now has the original merge commit, but no revert.

2) Do a rebase on `develop`, specifying the hash of the commit from which both `develop` and `feature` originated.  By default, rebase will ignore the merge commit entirely, thereby removing it:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase <SHA-1>
```

where `<SHA-1>` here is from the commit whence `feature` branched off from `develop`.

After these two steps, your `develop` branch will have neither merge commit nor revert commit, and you should be safe merging it into `feature`.

I *strongly* recommend reading the answer given by @torek in this question:

[Accidentally merged in wrong branch to mine. Is there a way to remove these unwanted files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263022/accidentally-merged-in-wrong-branch-to-mine-is-there-a-way-to-remove-these-unwa/42263096#42263096)

Answer (score 1):

Normally you make a feature branch and you work on that branch to complete your feature. Then you merge your feature to the develop branch and after some time the develop state goes live.

In your case if you have changes on the develop branch i would prefer a rebase on your feature branch. Then you get all changes and your feature branch is rewritten to the last commit of your dev branch.

Atlassian has a good tutorial how you can work with feature branches.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows#feature-branch-workflow

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem.  Why would we want to rebase _develop_ on _feature_ to bring commits from the former into the latter?

Comment: no your rebase your feature branch on the same state as your develop then you have all new changes and in your log it looks like you have made a new branch from that new position.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't this bring in the revert, thereby erasing his other work in the `feature` branch?  There is no way to let `develop` interact with `feature` without this happening, unless we do away with the bad merge.

Comment: Good point perhaps the problem was much easier then understood. But i will make some test and try that case :)

Comment: Yes, the question is confusing, and the workflow you describe might have avoided the problem in the first place, perhaps which is what the OP wants.